# Actions on Google Account linking client_id and client_secret missing in grant_type: 'authorization_code'

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google, google-authentication

My Oauth flow was working earlier in node 6. I've not tested the flow lately. But now after I migrated to Node 8.0 on google cloud functions, I stopped getting the `client_id` and `client_secret` for the `grant_type='authorization_code'`. This doesn't seem like an issue with my code because it is Google that need to send these parameters. And Google is sending these parameters for the previous GET requests!

I've followed the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?oauth=code#actionsdk

The flow is working flawlessly until the section: Exchange authorization codes for access tokens and refresh tokens. Here I am receiving the POST request, but the request body is not containing the required `client_id` and `client_secret` values.
I am getting following request.body

Req body is:

```
{ 
  grant_type: 'authorization_code', 
  code: 'ab09286808993bbfcd8fdd8049e9a40256ab5ec64de076f3cca.............c',
  redirect_uri: 'https://oauth-redirect.googleusercontent.com/r/roo-fire' 
}
```

Please help me understand what is going wrong!

--- Edited as per the comment - adding Account Linking section of Actions on Google ---

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e_HCjX8aDvhDnXh8qzGG_Ly3rUEkpOkB

Comment: This does seem odd. Can you update your question with the settings from the Actions Console "Account linking" section? Are you seeing the same problem when the Assistant is trying to use a refresh token?

Comment: Thank you @Prisoner, I've updated the question with the Account Linking information

Comment: I couldn't test it when using refresh token, becuse the application didn't pass through the `authorization_code` section.

Comment: @Prisoner I've tried to bypass the `client_id` and `client_secret` check for the `authorization_code`. Even in the `refresh_token` requests, I am not getting the `client_id` and `client_secret`

Comment: I tried to change the values for both `client_id` and `client_secret `on Google Actions console and verified the entire flow, to rule out any caching issues on the Google side!. Again the same problem.